# How to get a dotted page indicator for UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have a **UICollectionView** that has the following settings,

```
public CollectionView(CollectionLayout layout) : base(CGRect.Empty, layout)
{
    RegisterClassForCell(typeof(CollectionCell), CollectionCell.CellIdentifier);
    CollectionViewLayout = layout;
    ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    PagingEnabled = true;
}
```

The **CollectionViewLayout** is,

```
public CollectionLayout()
{
    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;
    MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0f;
    MinimumLineSpacing = 0f;
    ItemSize = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 200f);
}
```

so the cells in the CollectionView are stretched so that a cell fills the CollectionView. The CollectionView is only horizontally scrollable.

Now I want to have a dotted page indicator instead of the scroll bar for the CollectionView. Is there anyway I can achieve this properly?

Comment: You can use UIPageControl for the same https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Perfectly correct approach for 2020:

Simply add a `UIPageControl` in storyboard.

Put it below (i.e., visible on top of) your collection view.

[image]

Link to it...

```
class YourVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,
         UICollectionViewDataSource,
         UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var dots: UIPageControl!
```

Simply add a constraint centering it horizontally to the collection view, and add a constraint to align the bottoms.

That will give the standard positioning / spacing.

(Of course, you can place the dots anywhere you want, but that is the standard.)

[image]

## Tip 1 - colors

Bizarrely the **default colors** for the dots are .. clear!

So set them to gray/black or whatever you wish:

[image]

Or you can do that in code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dots.pageIndicatorTintColor = .systemGray5
    dots.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .yourCorporateColor
}
```

Next. In `numberOfItemsInSection`, add ...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
              numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    let k = ... yourData.count, or whatever your count is
    
    dots.numberOfPages = k
    return k
}
```

## Tip 2 - in fact, do *NOT* use the deceleration calls

Add this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    dots.currentPage = Int(
        (collectionView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.frame.width)
            .rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
        )
    )
}
```

You simply set the page in "scrollViewDidScroll".

In fact

• **do not use** `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`

• **do not use** `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.

To see why: try it using either of those calls. Now **skim quickly** through many pages. Notice it **does not** work properly.

Simply use `scrollViewDidScroll` for the correct, perfect result, including initialization.

## Tip 3 - do *NOT* use Int division - it completely changes the behavior and is totally wrong.

You will often see this example code:

```
// wrong, do not do this
dots.currentPage = Int(collectionView.contentOffset.x) /
                     Int(collectionView.frame.width)
// wrong, do not do this
```

## That often-seen example code is *completely wrong*.

If you try that, it will result in the dots **"jumping" in a non-standard way**, as you **skim** through pages.

Best explanation is to try it and see.

For the usual, correct, Apple-style behavior as you scroll through or skim through the pages, the code is:

```
    dots.currentPage = Int(
        (collectionView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.frame.width)
        .rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
    )
```

Final example...

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t “ .rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)” have no effect?

Comment: @ScottyBlades good question, that is specifically and definitely the one to use to get the "standard effect" (exactly per Apple).  As I mention, it is difficult to explain the different physics behaviors but, be sure to try it with `.rounded.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` and then in comparison try some of the other .rounded options.  Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Drag a UIPageControl above your collectionView and make an IBOutlet of UIPageControl in your ViewController.

Then Put the following code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(self.collectionView=.contentOffset.x)/ Int(self.collectionView.frame.width)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use UIPageControl. Link Below:
[UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol)

Then detect which cell you are in and write some code to change the "currentPage" of UIPageControl.